# Service Builder in Liferay order by modifyDate field

Tags: database, service, liferay, liferay-service-builder

I have set `order` as following in my `service.xml`:

```
<order by="desc">
    <order-column name="modifiedDate" order-by="desc" />
</order>
```

But when I call `getReglas(int start, int end);`, the list returned is ordered by `id` (as saved in database). I need to get the list ordered by `modifyDate` and I don't know how :(

I need to do something like:

```
select * From regla order by modifiedDate desc;
```

Someone can help me please? :(

Comment: [***Cross posted***](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/89232484)

Comment: Did you try removing `by="desc"` from `order` tag?, as you are already using it on `order-column` column.

Comment: thank you!! and i'm sorry for the Grammaticals errors :(

Comment: Set order `by` on `order` tag, when you want to set single order by for all / any specified `order-column`, otherwise, if you want to set separate order by for specified `order-column`, then set `order-by` on column tag itself.

Comment: it's solved thank you sooooo muuuuuch for your help!!!! emoticon

the problem was that liferay don't deploy well the portlet and leave the same configuration in the portlet of webapps emoticon

Answer (score 0):

it's solved thank you sooooo muuuuuch for your help!!!! emoticon

the problem was that liferay don't deploy well the portlet and leave the same configuration in the portlet of webapps emoticon